# DTO - Interface x Class

Tags: interface, typescript

Tenho usado Interface para criar DTO (Data Transfer Objects), objetos "burros" que só servem para padronizar a comunicação de objetos entre o front e o back. A minha questão é a seguinte: Realmente usar Interface é a melhor prática? Ou seria melhor usar classes? Qual a opinião de vocês a respeito disso?

Ex:

```
interface UserDTO {

    name?: string;
    mailAddress?: string;
    phone?: string;
}

 params: UserDTO;

_save(user): void {

   this.params = {};

   this.params.name = user.name;
   this.params.mailAddress = user.mailAddress;
   this.params.phone = user.phone;

   [...]
}
```

Acabo tendo que definir as propriedades como `nullable` para poder inicializar a interface com objeto vazio, para que não ocorra *null reference exception*. É exatamente isso que está me incomodando. Caso utilizasse classe resolveria isso instanciando um objeto `User`. Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Obrigado. Estava fazendo isso agora.

Answer (score 0):

A interface pode ser uma forma de tipar uma estrutura JSON. A vantagem de usar interface direto é tratar o objeto como um JSON puro. Visto que assim permite você criar o objeto direto nesta notação.

EX:

```
this.params = {
     name: "Nome",
     mailAddress: "mail@mail.com",
     phone: "55555555"
}
```

Como você quer criar um JSON com campos que podem não existir, seria mais prático realmente usar Classe. Porém você teria que converter esta para JSON antes de salvar:

```
class UserDTO {

    name: string;
    mailAddress: string;
    phone: string;
}

params: {} = {};

_save(user: UserDTO): void {

    this.params = JSON.stringify(user);

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que são duas questões separadas. Por partes.

#### Evitar a exceção na criação diretamente a partir da interface

Para evitar exceção de null na inicialização vazia da interface, basta que você inicialize o objeto diretamente, assim:

```
this.params = {
     name: user.name,
     mailAddress: user.mailAddress,
     phone: user.phone
}
```

Isso permite criar o objeto diretamente, **e ao mesmo tempo** impede a criação de um objeto com alguma propriedade null, onde isso não seja permitido pela interface.

É isso que você provavelmente quer, para evitar entrada de nulls no seu processamento.

#### Criar um objeto "vazio", padrão, para mutação posterior

Para criar um objeto vazio, que seja ao mesmo tempo válido, você daí sim precisa usar classes, para que possa informar inicializadores padrão em cada propriedade ou um construtor que preencha as variáveis com valores padrão ou alguma computação.

Nesse caso, para manter o "jeitão" geral de usar interfaces no DTO, pode-se criar uma classe `DtoDefault` que implementa um `Dto` em particular. Assim, a interface permanece "pura", só informando como os dados *são*, e quaisquer defaults são encontrados numa classe separada.